# Write a query to find the name of the student(s) who has scored maximum mark in Software Engineering. Sort the result based on name

Tags: oracle

Write a query to find the name of the student(s) who has scored maximum mark in Software Engineering. Sort the result based on name.

This is what I tried.

```
select s.student_name 
  from student s,mark m,subject su
  where s.student_id=m.student_id and su.subject_id=m.subject_id and max(m.value)in 
  (select value from mark where lower(su.subject_name)='software engineering')
   order by s.student_name;
```

I am not getting the proper result.[image: This is the schema]

Comment: It has nothing to do with your question but please use explicit joins in your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the fact that you're using outdated implicit comma syntax for joins, you are also combining columns of the tables in the wrong way in the sub query.

`subject_name` is a column of `subject` which has nothing to do with the student's relation to marks. So, mark may be joined separately with subject while determining the student_ids with highest mark. We can then obtain the name of the student using those student_ids

So, In Oracle 12c and above, you could do

```
SELECT s.student_name
   FROM student s
WHERE s.student_id IN ( SELECT m.student_id
                        FROM mark m JOIN subject su 
                         ON su.subject_id = m.subject_id
                        WHERE lower(su.subject_name) = 'software engineering'
                           ORDER BY m.value DESC
                        FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS WITH TIES ) order by 1;
```

For previous versions, you may use `dense_rank` or `rank`

```
SELECT s.student_name
   FROM student s
WHERE s.student_id IN ( SELECT student_id
                        FROM ( SELECT m.*,DENSE_RANK() OVER(
                                    ORDER BY m.value DESC
                               ) AS rnk
                               FROM mark m  JOIN subject su 
                                ON su.subject_id = m.subject_id
                        WHERE lower(su.subject_name) = 'software engineering'
                    ) WHERE rnk = 1
               ) order by 1;
```

Comment: After replacing s.value with m.value now it is working fine. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @AnuvanshChauhan : You're welcome. Always remember to provide table definitions / sample data while asking a SQL question, it will help us provide you a working solution

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the max function in the subquery instead of the main query.

```
select s.student_name
  from student s, mark m, subject su
 where s.student_id = m.student_id
   and su.subject_id = m.subject_id
   and m.value in
       (select max(value)
          from mark
         where lower(su.subject_name) = 'software engineering')
 order by s.student_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. It must work perfectly :

```
 select s.student_name
    from student s
    join mark m
    on s.student_id=m.student_id
    join subject s1
    on s1.subject_id=m.subject_id
    where m.value=(select max(m1.value) from mark m1 
                     join subject s2
                     on s2.subject_id=m1.subject_id
                     where lower(s2.subject_name)='software engineering'
    group by s2.subject_id)
    group by s.student_name
    order by s.student_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select student_name
from student join mark using(student_id) join subject using(subject_id)
where subject_name = 'Software Engineering' 
and value = (select max(value)
            from mark join subject using (subject_id)
            where subject_name = 'Software Engineering')
order by student_name;
```

This is very self-explanatory solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
select student_name
from student s join mark m on s.student_id=m.student_id 
join subject sub on m.subject_id=sub.subject_id
where lower(sub.subject_name)='software engineering' and 
m.value = (select max(m1.value)
             from mark m1 join subject sub1 on m1.subject_id=sub1.subject_id
             where lower(sub1.subject_name)='software engineering')
order by student_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

select student_name
from stundent
where student_id in(
select student_id
from mark
where value=(select max(value) from mark
where subject_id=(
select subject_id
from subject
where lower(subject_name)='software engineering'
)
)
)
)
order by student_name;

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

```
select student_name
from student
where student_id in 
(select student_id 
from subject join mark using(subject_id)
where value in
(select max(value)
from mark
group by student_id
having initcap(subject_name) = 'Software Engineering'))
order by student_name;
```